# .so file the constructor not found

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, undefined-reference

I created a `.so` file on my computer and it's working,
but when I'm cloning the code, and trying to create the `.so` again using the commands:

```
cmake ..
sudo make install
```

it creates the shared object, but when I'm trying to build the project I'm getting:

> void
>   __gnu_cxx::new_allocator::construct,
>   std::allocator >&>(InventoryManager*,
>   std::__cxx11::basic_string,
>   std::allocator >&)':
>   /usr/local/include/c++/7.4.0/ext/new_allocator.h:136: undefined
>   reference to
>   `InventoryManager::InventoryManager(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator > cons

How do I make it work?

This is my CMakeList.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(InventoryManager VERSION 1.0.1 DESCRIPTION "InventoryManager v 1.0.1")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
add_library(InventoryManager SHARED
          src/InventoryItem.cpp
          src/InventoryItemFactory.cpp
          src/InventoryManager.cpp)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(InventoryManager PROPERTIES
        VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
        SOVERSION 1
        PUBLIC_HEADER include/InventoryItem.hpp
                    include/InventoryItemFactory.hpp
                    include/InventoryManager.hpp)
configure_file(InventoryManager.pc.in InventoryManager.pc @ONLY)
target_include_directories(InventoryManager PRIVATE .)
install(TARGETS InventoryManager
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
install(FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/InventoryManager.pc
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/pkgconfig)
```

**EDIT** 
this is the constructor from InventoryManager.cpp

```
#include <cmath>
#include <functional>
#include <include/InventoryManager.hpp>
#include <iostream>

InventoryManager::InventoryManager(const std::string &symbol):m_Symbol(symbol),m_itemFactory(*(new InventoryItemFactory(symbol)))
{
    m_InventoryQty = 0;
    m_InventoryItemValue = 0;
    m_TotalInventoryValue = 0;
    m_CurrentInventoryValue = 0;

}
```

and here is the declaration in .h file

```
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include "InventoryItem.hpp"
#include "InventoryItemFactory.hpp"

class InventoryManager
{
public:
      explicit InventoryManager(const std::string &symbol);
    /* more functions */
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code for `InventoryManager.cpp` and the other referenced files? It is hard to suggest solutions without having a [Minimal, Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @squareskittles I solved the problem but it wasn't because of the so but because of stdc++.so the sl was broken, so after i fix it the program runnig